# Search multiple strings for multiple words

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing a sentence per row. I need to search through these sentences for the occurence of certain words. This is how I currently do it:

```
import pandas as pd

p = pd.DataFrame({"sentence" : ["this is a test", "yet another test", "now two tests", "test a", "no test"]})

test_words = ["yet", "test"]
p["word_test"] = ""
p["word_yet"]  = ""

for i in range(len(p)):
    for word in test_words:
        p.loc[i]["word_"+word] = p.loc[i]["sentence"].find(word)
```

This works as intended, however, is it possible to optimize this? It runs fairly slow for large dataframes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [str.find](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.find.html)

```
p['word_test'] = p.sentence.str.find('test')
p['word_yet'] = p.sentence.str.find('yet')

    sentence         word_test  word_yet    word_yest
0   this is a test   10         -1          -1
1   yet another test 12          0          0
2   now two tests    8          -1          -1
3   test a           0          -1          -1
4   no test          3          -1          -1
```

Answer (score 5):

IIUC, use a simple list comprehension and call `str.find` for each word:

```
u = pd.DataFrame({
    # 'word_{}'.format(w)
    f'word_{w}': df.sentence.str.find(w) for w in test_words}, index=df.index)
u
   word_yet  word_test
0        -1         10
1         0         12
2        -1          8
3        -1          0
4        -1          3
```

---

```
pd.concat([df, u], axis=1)

           sentence  word_yet  word_test
0    this is a test        -1         10
1  yet another test         0         12
2     now two tests        -1          8
3            test a        -1          0
4           no test        -1          3
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you mentioned better performance using `np.char.find`

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=[np.char.find(p.sentence.values.astype(str),x) for x in test_words],index=test_words,columns=p.index)
pd.concat([p,df.T],axis=1)
Out[32]: 
           sentence  yet  test
0    this is a test   -1    10
1  yet another test    0    12
2     now two tests   -1     8
3            test a   -1     0
4           no test   -1     3
```